# How do I set up my e-mail to this web form?

Tags: php, html

I finally figured out how to create sliding down web form but where and how do I set up my e-mail address. So, when somebody sends me the message I got the same message right into my e-mail. I guess this is a basic question but I just can't find the answer.

Here is the link to JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8S82T/101/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Jquery test</title>

    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" />

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">

        <div id="button" class="title">
            <h6>Contact</h6>
        </div>

        <div id="dropbox">
            <header class="title">
                <h6>Whats up?</h6>
            </header>

            <div class="contact-form">
                <form action="lulzy.php" action="post">
                        <h6><img src="img/person.png" alt="" /> Name</h6>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Please enter your full name here" required />
                        <h6><img src="img/email.png" alt="" /> E-mail</h6>
                    <input type="email" placeholder="Please enter your e-mail address" required/>
                        <h6><img src="img/message.png" alt="" /> Message</h6>
                    <textarea placeholder="Type your message..." required/></textarea>

                    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

<script src="dropbox.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are probably going to need to use a server side language

Comment: COuld you please be more specific. I am very new to coding. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have already added the action`lulzy.php` to you form

You need to add the below code into that file `lulzy.php`

```
<?php
  $name= $_REQUEST['name'] ;
  $email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
  $message = $_REQUEST['message'] ;

  mail( "yourname@example.com", "Feedback Form Results",
    $message, "From: $email" );
  header( "Location: http://www.example.com/thankyou.html" );
?>
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try this but not really sure how to do it. Should I just open txt file and add this code and then save it as .php?

Comment: @C.Felipe yes exactly. Once you save it in `php` ,drop the file in same directory. Also don't forget to change your email  in file and default thank you page :)

Comment: Thank you Deonia! Appreciate your kind help with my basic question. Also, wanted to ask you if this is a safe option to do or I need to enter a validation option???

Comment: @C.Felipe Yeah it is safe for now. But I can see there are no validation check except `required` in your webform. Nowadays spamming in emails is in peak and web robots are sending the sapmmin emails if they find a form without captcha or any other validation while crawling . As per now you can use this but later you can add captcha human validation in the form . Read here how to add it http://www.html-form-guide.com/contact-form/html-contact-form-captcha.html

Answer (score 4):

[Here](http://www.freecontactform.com/html_form.php) is a good tutorial for you

It involves the usage of the server side language PHP.

This script in particular also uses some validation to make sure that the person sending you something isn't spamming you

You will also need to add the `name` attribute into your inputs. They should be `name`, `email`, and `comments`.

```php
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

// CHANGE THE TWO LINES BELOW
$email_to = "you@yourdomain.com"; // put your email here

$email_subject = "Website HTML form submissions"; // put the subject here


function died($error) {
    // your error code can go here
    echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
    echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
    echo $error."<br /><br />";
    echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
    die();
}

// validation expected data exists
if(!isset($_POST['name']) ||
    !isset($_POST['email'])     ||
    !isset($_POST['comments'])) {
    died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');      
}

$name = $_POST['name']; // required
$email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
$comments = $_POST['comments']; // required

$error_message = "";
$email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
  $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
$string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
if(!preg_match($string_exp,$name)) {
  $error_message .= 'The Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
  $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
  died($error_message);
}
$email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

function clean_string($string) {
  $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
  return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
}

$email_message .= "Name: ".clean_string($name)."\n";
$email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n
$email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";


// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers); 
?>

 <!-- place your own success html here -->

<?php
}
die();
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!!! I have to go through this code and try to understand it but I believe this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

OK, I have added names and ids to your form and created a javascript function validate() (I have that in my header)- by giving the elementss ids, it then enables the getelement by id
The onsubmit returns false if all the fields are not entered. The "email" element in the html corrects for the correct email format.
The php is a double check against spam.
Hope this helps.

```
        <div class="contact-form">
            <form  onsubmit="return Validate();" action="lulzy.php" action="post" name="contact">
                    <h6><img src="img/person.png" alt="" /> Name</h6>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Please enter your full name here" name="fname" id="fname" />
                    <h6><img src="img/email.png" alt="" /> E-mail</h6>
                <input type="email" placeholder="Please enter your e-mail address" name="email" id="email"/>
                    <h6><img src="img/message.png" alt="" /> Message</h6>
                <textarea placeholder="Type your message..." name="message" id="message"/></textarea>
                 <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>
        </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function Validate()
    {
        // create array containing textbox elements
        var inputs = [document.getElementById('fname'), document.getElementById('email'), document.getElementById('message')];

        var error;

        for(var i = 0; i<inputs.length; i++)
        // loop through each element to see if value is empty
        {
            if(inputs[i].value == '')
            {
                error = 'Please complete all fields.';
                alert(error);
                return false;
                }
        }
     }
```

```
 include ("contact.html");

    function spamcheck($field)
  {
  //filter_var() sanitizes the e-mail
  //address using FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL
  $field=filter_var($field, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);

  //filter_var() validates the e-mail
  //address using FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL
  if(filter_var($field, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
    {
    return TRUE;
    }
  else
    {
    return FALSE;
    }
  }

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    //process form data
  //check if the email address is invalid
  $mailcheck = spamcheck($_POST['email']);
 if ($mailcheck==TRUE){

  //send email
  $email=$_POST['email'];
  $fname=$_POST['fname'];
   $message = $_POST['message'] ;
  $subject="website contact";
  mail("your email address", $subject ,$message , "From: $email");
 echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("Your form has been submitted.")
```

'

http://jsfiddle.net/yvytty/zLfgL/1/ (without php)

Comment: Thank you a lot! I really have a lot of materials to work on for the whole weekend. Really appreciate your kindness!!! Have a great day!

Comment: Maybe you can just add a link to JSFiddle or something similar?

Answer (score 1):

Very easy solution, but also very amateurish would be changing the `action` of your form. You could do:

```
action="mailto:yourmail@domain;com"
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ywah9/

---

A better solution would be creating a submit page where you process the form using `PHP`. Mini example:

```
$body = 'New email submitted:' . $_POST['email'];
mail( 'yourmail@domain.ext' , 'Contact form website' , $body )
```

The example above is VERY basic just to give you a head start!

Comment: This would work if it was a button that linked to his html. But he wants to send a contact form

Comment: @CodyGuldner Sorry but this works. See http://jsfiddle.net/ywah9/

Comment: Not sure if I put this question correctly. All I want is that when somebody visits my website and wants to contact me, the message that the user types into this form, comes directly to my e-mail. Let's say that my address is: mymail@domain.com

Comment: Wrote a very basic PHP example of how you could process the form

Comment: Thank you, thank you! I will go through all your suggestions and try to understand how everything works!